# Gershgorin-type bounds for smallest eigenvalue of positive-definite matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, upper-lower-bounds, gershgorin-sets

I would like to know if there are known results for bounding eigenvalues of positive-definite matrices, in particular gram matrices $AA^T$ based on easily computable functions of $A$.

Gershgorin bounds are too loose for the smallest eigenvalue of a gram matrix, typically giving negative bounds, which are of course vacuous for a gram matrix.

Comment: There is the Hadamard inequality, which is not what you are after, but maybe it is also useful for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality#Alternate_forms_and_corollaries

Comment: If the Gram matrix $AA^T$ is non-singular, Gerschgorin method can be used for the largest eigenvalue of its inverse. Say that you find an interval $(a,b), a,b>0.$ The bounds for the smallest eigenvalue of $AA^T$ are the inverses of the above, hence $(1/b,1/a).$

Comment: @user376343 How would I proceed in bounding the largest eigenvalues of the inverse? Any general idea or it is too case specific?

Comment: If you have the inverse matrix, say B, use Gerschgorin circle theorem. If the largest eigenvalue $\mu$ of B satisfies $a\leq \mu \leq b,$ then the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $AA^T$ satisfies $1/b \leq \lambda \leq 1/a $ This is so because eigenvalues of a matrix and of it's inverse are inverse.